# Selecting xpath - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am coding a bot for tinder with selenium but its not working. Here is my code.

```
fb_button =  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/span/div[2]/button')

fb_button.click()
```

This code is for clicking the facebook login button. However when i run the code, it dont work healthy.I am getting an error like this.

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate e
lement: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div
[2]/div/div/span/div[2]/button"}
```

However when i try to create an object and try to call this function, it returns something.

HTML of the button:

```
<button type="button" class="button Lts($ls-s) Z(0) CenterAlign Mx(a) Cur(p) Tt(u) Bdrs(100px) Px(24px) Px(20px)--s Py(0) Mih(42px)--s Mih(50px)--ml button--outline Bdw(2px) Bds(s) Trsdu($fast) Bdc(#fff) C(#fff) Bdc(#fff):h C(#fff):h Bdc(#fff):f C(#fff):f Bdc(#fff):a C(#fff):a Fw($semibold) focus-button-style W(100%) Fz(4vw)--ms" draggable="false" aria-label="Facebook ile oturum aç"><span class="Pos(r) Z(1) D(ib)">Facebook ile oturum aç</span></button>
```

Comment: Please add the html of the button in the question

Comment: @SameerArora added.

Comment: add wait for getting element because sometimes page load then the element is present in HTML.

Comment: i added a 6 seconds sleep time before selecting the xpath but it isnt working.

Comment: check your XPath correctly because it gives NoSuchElementException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can wait until the element can clickable and present in HTML dom.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

fb_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "your_xpath")))
fb_button.click()
```

you can check the wait conditions [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)!

Answer (score 2):

You can click on the element using xpath:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Facebook ile oturum aç']"))).click()
```

**Note: You have to add the following imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```